# Strange behaviour with File IO in C

Tags: c, file-io

I'm having some crazy issues with File IO in C. I'm writing a programming language in C. I'm currently on Linux, one of my friends on Windows has pulled the repository from GitHub, used GCC to build it and run [this test file](https://github.com/freefouran/jayfor/blob/master/tests/test.j4).

Basically, the program takes the file splits it up into tokens and parses it. The issue here, I have narrowed down to the File IO side of the program. Basically when you read a file, it adds on some weird tokens at the end, here's a debug sample my friend sent me.

```
Unrecognized identifier found: `VER`
int,
x, =, 5, ;, int, y, =, 10, ;, fn, func_name, (, double, y, ,, int, x, ,, int, zx
asdfqasd_asd, =, 123, ), :, int,
{, }, fn, something_else, (, ), :, void, {, }, fn, main, (, ), :, void, {, somet
hing_else, (, ), ;, func_name, (, 5, ,,
5, ), ;, }, VER, =, \, \, MURRAY, -, P, <END_OF_FILE>,
```

Notice at the end:

```
, VER, =, \, \, MURRAY, -, P, <END_OF_FILE>,
```

Which is this string tokenized:

```
VER=\\MURRAY-P
```

Which is a scrambled version of:

```
LOGONSERVER=\\MURRAY-PC-2
```

Whenever we debug with a file, depending on where the file is (local, absolute path) a different system variable is appended onto the file. I'm not sure what source is relevant here, so sorry for this but I can only think of linking the entire repository [here](https://github.com/freefouran/jayfor).

Any help would be amazing, since I feel out of control as I'm using Linux. Any extra details you need, just ask :)

Comment: Need source example of the code doing the reading.

Comment: Sure, [reads file](https://github.com/freefouran/jayfor/blob/master/src/scanner.c#L13).

Comment: Apparently, when they use a forward slash it's okay, but with backslashes it breaks. Any ideas?

Comment: to debug if it is in the reading or the later tokenizing, after reading `printf("%s",scanner->contents);` -- if that prints fine, then you need to debug your tokenizer.

Comment: I think it is the tokenizer, in [this file](https://github.com/freefouran/jayfor/blob/master/src/lexer.c#L47). But I'll quickly check.

Comment: Also, even though `ftell` should be right, since you opened in `"r"` mode instead of `"rb"` you can be getting translation, so the `fileLength` returned by `fread()` can give you a different length (longer if Unix-line ending are translated to DOS ones from the source file, etc) than `ftell()`.  Your issue may go away if you `fopen()` with `"rb"`

Comment: Giving them both a go, just gotta wait for my friend to pull and check for me :)

Comment: I think the RB thing worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `ftell` should be right, since you opened in `"r"` mode instead of `"rb"` you can be getting translation, so the fileLength returned by `fread()` can give you a different length (longer if Unix-line ending are translated to DOS ones from the source file, etc) than `ftell()` does. Your issue may go away if you `fopen()` with `"rb"`